# Convert whole String in integer value in android

Tags: android, string, format, decimal

I have a problem while converting the whole string in integer.
When I write in edittext "Hello" and when I press button then in other edittext , it should show me 
72 101 108 108 111 .
Please help me...

My .xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Message" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"

        android:text="@string/Decimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

        android:ems="10" 

        android:hint="@string/Decimal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert each character to int from entered string. 
Sample code below might help you:

```
String str = "Hello";
String strInt = "";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  strInt += (int)c + " ";
}
System.out.println(strInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well just cast characters to int and you get the ascii value.

```
StringBuilder stringToAppendInts = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder stringToAppendHexs = new StringBuilder();

for(char item : myString.toCharArray()){
   stringToAppendHexs.append(Integer.toHexString((int)item) +" ");
   stringToAppendInts.append( (int)item+" ");
}

edittext.setText(stringToAppendInts.toString());
edittext.setText(stringToAppendHexs.toString());
```

Comment: What about use rather `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of `String`? You should know that `String` is immutable and if he will have for example text generated from some file.txt with big size so your approach will be too much memory consume.

Comment: @Gjordis..can you tell me how to convert String to Hex value..??

Comment: @sajmon_d He asked "String". I answered with a String

Comment: Now it contains conversion to decimal and hex integers. base 10 and base 16

Comment: @Gjordis and you should tell him that it is not good to do it right that. Then it looks like that many applications are not correctly implemented and aren't safe. This is recommendation not rule.

Comment: @sajmon_d Do you mean building the new strings like so, or should the iteration be done somehow with stringbuffer? I'm not familiar with all the optimizations in Java.